# Getting permission denied every time permission is asked in google chrome Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I am using Notification.requestPermission() to get the permission from the user in my React JS application. If the permission somehow gets revoked then the chrome for Android, does not allow the popup again, it automatically results denied on requesting the permission. e.g. One scenario for that is when user installs the PWA and gives the notification permission he gets the notications. But if he deletes the PWA and opens the url in the browser, permissions will be revoked and he will not be able to get the popup again. The Notification.requestPermission() will automatically return denied. The Notification.permission is default at this point.

When the Notification.permission is default and Notification.requestPermission() is called, it should show the popup to the user to ask permission instead of denying it automatically.